# Node js create folder and insert file in google drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am looking for creating a folder inside the specified folder and want to insert file to the create one folder.
I am using [google-drive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-drive) library and

here they have provided API like

```
googleDrive(token).files().insert(meta, params, callback)
```

I have parent folder id , name for sub folder and file in bytearray. so for my situation what should be meta, param for the insert function.

Answer (score 4):

Check the NodeJS implementation for [Inserting a file in a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) as according to the docs, a folder is essentially a file.

```
var folderId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E';
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': 'photo.jpg',
  parents: [ folderId ]
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
  body: fs.createReadStream('files/photo.jpg')
};
drive.files.create({
   resource: fileMetadata,
   media: media,
   fields: 'id'
}, function(err, file) {
  if(err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }
});
```